OPENVPN Отсутствуют конфиг файлы и не работает tun
Всё делается в virtualbox на версии kali 2024.3
Хотел подключиться к машине на tryhackme, вроде сделал всё как говорилось в инструкции, сначала apt update && apt upgrade , потом apt install openvpn, скачиваю файл для подключения и при попытке подключения 
после попытки добавить в конфиг файл dev tun0 или dev tun, я не нашёл этот файл в /etc/openvpn, попытался найти , начал искать в /etc/networkmanager как говорилось на сайтах- аналогично. Я предположил, что должен собственными руками скачать в интернете конфиг файл или текст из него и вставить , но не нашёл ничего ни на ру сайтах, ни на англ сайтах. Помогите решить проблему и подключиться к tryhackme.

Челу на реддите помогло перекачать конфиг около тридцати раз
